# How do I get the user firstname in wordpress?

Tags: php, utf-8, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Here's my code in wordpress functions.php. I want to display user information in gravity form fields The top function works but the bottom doesn't and I can't figure out what to use to display first name.

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_pm_id', 'populate_pm_id');
function populate_pm_id($value){
    return $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); 
    echo $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); 

}

add_filter('gform_field_value_pm_firstname', 'populate_pm_firstname');
function populate_pm_firstname($value){
    return $user_info->first_name = get current_user_first_name(); 
    echo $user_info->first_name = get_current_user_first_name();

}
```

Comment: Seems to work but now I am getting a related Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_User could not be converted to string in /wp-includes/formatting.php on line 766. I found a thread that relates at https://wordpress.org/support/topic/catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-wp_error-could-not-be-converted-to-string-11. Seems this conflicts with a null return.

Answer (score 6):

Try this code to get user first name and last name.

```
<?php 
      $user_info = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
      $first_name = $user_info->first_name;
      $last_name = $user_info->last_name;
      echo "$first_name $last_name";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like it should be working now, but I'm getting a related error. I've started another thread at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020237/calling-paramenter-get-utf8-null-return-error-in-formatting-php if you'd like to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

yo can get the user and its data via

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

to get the first name from that object, you need to

```
$first_name = $current_user->user_firstname;
```

you will still get an user object, even if you are not logged in.
here is a var_dump on a non-logged-in user:

```
object(WP_User)#1265 (8) {
  ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#1267 (0) {}
  ["ID"]=> int(0)
  ["caps"]=> array(0) {}
  ["cap_key"]=> NULL
  ["roles"]=> array(0) {}
  ["allcaps"]=> array(0) {}
  ["filter"]=> NULL
  ["site_id":"WP_User":private]=> int(0)
}
```

more infos and details [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/).